# Change Windows [Ctrl+Tab] Key Binding to the Emacs Key Binding Ctrl + x o which changes windows

Tags: python, linux, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I always want to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> when coding in python to switch to another window just coded in from emacs usage but ipython doesn't understand that as a key binding nor any other program for that matter. Then came to the conclusion I'd love to have emacs style key binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> to switch windows which I don't think would be possible but just curious if anyone has tried something similar. I run Debian based linux currently Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: So to clarify, this isn't about Windows, Emacs, or Python? You just want to be able to use `Ctrl+x o` in Ubuntu to do what `Ctrl+TAB` currently does?

Comment: I did a bit of googling and found [how-do-i-remap-certain-keys](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys)

Comment: @VenkatH thanks for that but that just changes key assignments. I guess you would have to force the operating system to not act on Ctrl+x and wait for future input. I just wasn't sure how to do this.

Comment: @phils - Yes this comment was probably better elsewhere because as stated ubuntu would relate to ubuntu not reacting to C-X as a shortcut for "cut" and enabling emacs like key bindings for the C-x key. Not sure this is possible or relatively easy at all.